# Nginx - use proxy_cache_lock logic when cache expired in order to avoid multi-upstram request

Tags: nginx, caching, nginx-config

[Proxy_cache_lock](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_lock) logic means that when `NGINX` receives couple of request simultaneously, it sends only one upstream and the rest waiting till the first one returns and insert to cache (wait time is as configure in `proxy_cache_lock_timeout`).

If the cache element **expired**, and the `NGINX` receives couple of request simultaneously all of them are proxied to the upstream.

**Question:** How can I configure the `NGINX` to have the same logic as `proxy_cache_lock` also when the cache element exist but expired?

I checked [proxy_cache_use_stale](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_use_stale) but it is not what I'm looking for because its return the expired cache when updating and I need to wait till the answer return from upstream...

This is my current `NGINX` configuration file:

```
http {
    include         /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type    application/octet-stream;
    access_log          /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    proxy_cache_path @MY_CACHE_PATH@; # this obviously has the path in my file 
    proxy_cache_use_stale updating;
    proxy_cache_lock on;
    proxy_cache_lock_timeout 15s;
    proxy_cache_valid 404   10s;
    proxy_cache_valid 502   0s;
    proxy_cache one;

    server {
            listen 80;
            proxy_read_timeout 15s;
            proxy_connect_timeout 5s;
            include locations.conf;
    }
}
```

I managed to achieve this behavior by changing the `NGINX` source code but I wonder if that can be achieve within configuration

Comment: have you ever figured this out?

Comment: No - that stale fix most of the case and for the expired I still going to upstream for all the request

Comment: I thinks this is not possible with nginx cache. Maybe you can take a look into nusters cache feature [wait on|off|TIME](https://github.com/jiangwenyuan/nuster/#wait-onofftime-cache-only)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug, a lock should be an actual lock! this isn't even a problem with multiple nginx workers, a single worker still can issue 2 requests when the cache has expired, despite there being a lock!

Comment: Would you be able to share the NGINX source changes you needed to make to allow for this behavior?

Comment: Are you sure that the simultaneous requests to the upstream you are talking about are for the same key? 
Because the nginx documentation is clearly saying that `proxy_cache_lock on;` should be locking if the key is the same, no matter what other conditions you have.

Comment: Yes - same cache key. as you can see https://www.mail-archive.com/nginx@nginx.org/msg12044.html (from @pva answer)

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior [according to upstream](https://www.mail-archive.com/nginx@nginx.org/msg12044.html). As Maxim told there, in [the documentations it is said](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_lock):

> When enabled, only one request at a time will be allowed to
> populate a new cache element identified according to the
> proxy_cache_key directive by passing a request to a proxied server.

Now,

> Note "a new cache element". It does not work while updating cache
> elements, this is not implemented.

That said, could you share the code changes that work for you?

Comment: Thanks you for finding that source - good at least to know it is known. I was long ago so not so sure but I think it was changing https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/2485681308bd8d3108da31546cb91bb97813a3fb/src/http/ngx_http_file_cache.c#L646 to NGX_AGAIN (but not really remember...)